# How to configure to open application if click Notifications of my Electron js Applications In Windows Action Center (Notification Panel)

Tags: angular, windows, notifications, electron, desktop-application

I am using Electron js and angular to Create a application in that I am sending Notifications through my app using Notification in electron.If my notification are in windows panel or Action Center if I click that is not opening my app instead it is clearing I want it be open my app if I click that notification.

`

import { app, BrowserWindow, session, Event, nativeImage, Tray, ipcMain, Notification, globalShortcut, dialog } from 'electron';

import * as path from 'path';

import * as fs from 'fs';

import log from 'electron-log/main';

let win: BrowserWindow | null = null;

app.setAppUserModelId('Task Tracker Application');

let lastNotification: Notification;

let tray: Tray;

let isQuitting: boolean = false;

const args = process.argv.slice(1),

serve = args.some(val => val === '--serve');

ipcMain.on("Minimize", () => {

log.info('minimize works');

win?.minimize();

});

ipcMain.on("close", () => {

log.info('minimize works');

win?.hide();

showNotification('Task Tracker', 'Please find the app in icon tray.');

});

ipcMain.on("Maximize", () => {

log.info('Maximize Works');

win && (win.isMaximized() ? win.unmaximize() : win.maximize());

});

function createWindow(): BrowserWindow {

log.initialize();

const appData = app.getPath('userData');

log.transports.file.resolvePathFn = () => {

const today = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];

return path.join(appData, 'logs', `TaskTracker-${today}.log`);

};

const logFormat = '{level} | {y}-{m}-{d} {h}:{i}:{s}:{ms} | {text}';

log.transports.console.format = logFormat;

log.info('Log from the main process');

createTray();

win = new BrowserWindow({

x: 0,

y: 0,

width: 1200,

height: 800,

minWidth: 1200,

minHeight: 800,

frame: false,

autoHideMenuBar: true,

icon: path.join(__dirname,  'assets/logo.jpg'),

webPreferences: {

nodeIntegration: true,

allowRunningInsecureContent: (serve),

contextIsolation: false,

},

titleBarStyle: 'hidden'

});

win.setMenu(null)

win.webContents.openDevTools();

win.webContents.on('did-finish-load', () => {

const css = `body::-webkit-scrollbar { display: none; } body { -ms-overflow-style: none; scrollbar-width: none; }`;

if (win)

win.webContents.insertCSS(css);

});

if (serve) {

const debug = require('electron-debug');

debug();

require('electron-reloader')(module);

win.loadURL('http://localhost:4200');

} else {

let pathIndex = './index.html';

if (fs.existsSync(path.join(__dirname, '../dist/index.html'))) {

pathIndex = '../dist/index.html';

}

const url = new URL(path.join('file:', __dirname, pathIndex));

win.loadURL(url.href);

}

win.on('minimize', function (event: Event) {

event.preventDefault();

if (win)

win.hide();

showNotification('Task Tracker', 'Please find the app in icon tray.');

});

win.on('close', function (event: Event) {

log.info('app quit');

log.info('app-close');

globalShortcut.unregisterAll();

if (!isQuitting) {

event.preventDefault();

if (win)

win.hide();

showNotification('Task Tracker', 'Please find the app in icon tray.');

} else {

win = null;

}

});

win.on('closed', () => {

win = null;

});

return win;

}

function showNotification(title: string, message: string) {

if (lastNotification) {

lastNotification.close()

}

const notification = new Notification({

title: title,

body: message,

icon: path.join(__dirname,  'assets/logo.jpg'),

});

notification.on('click', () => {

if (win === null) {

createWindow();

}

else if (win && !win.isVisible()) {

win.show();

}

else if(win && win.isVisible()) {

win.show();

}

else {

if (win)

win.show();

}

})

notification.show();

lastNotification = notification

}

function createTray() {

const trayIcon = nativeImage.createFromPath(path.join(__dirname,  'assets/logo.jpg'));

tray = new Tray(trayIcon);

tray.setToolTip('Task Tracker');

tray.on('click', () => {

if (win && win.isVisible()) {

win.hide();

} else {

if (win)

win.show();

}

});

}

try {

app.on('ready', () => {

session.defaultSession.allowNTLMCredentialsForDomains('*');

createWindow();

function registerShortcut(key: string, message: string) {

globalShortcut.register(key, () => {

if (win) {

win.webContents.send(message);

if (!win.isVisible()) {

win.show();

}

}

});

}

registerShortcut('ALT+A', 'navigate-to-add-task');

registerShortcut('ALT+D', 'navigate-to-Dashboard');

registerShortcut('ALT+L', 'get-last-updated-tasks');

ipcMain.on('show-notification', (_event, { title, message }) => {

console.log(`Received IPC message to show notification. Title: ${title}, Message: ${message}`);

try {

showNotification(title, message);

console.log('Notification function called successfully.');

} catch (error) {

console.error('Error showing notification:', error);

}

});

});

app.on('before-quit', () => {

globalShortcut.unregisterAll();

log.info('inregister -app');

log.info('app inquit');

isQuitting = true;

});

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {

log.info('inregister -app');

log.info('app quit');

if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {

app.quit();

}

});

app.on('activate', () => {

if (win === null) {

createWindow();

}

});

} catch (e) {

}`

[Attached Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akcYv.jpg)

> I am Tried default Notification method but it is opening when notification comes but not opening in windows notification panel or Action Center

`

function showNotification(title: string, message: string) {

if (lastNotification) {

lastNotification.close()

}

const notification = new Notification({

title: title,

body: message,

icon: path.join(__dirname,  'assets/logo.jpg'),

});

notification.on('click', () => {

if (win === null) {

createWindow();

}

else if (win && !win.isVisible()) {

win.show();

}

else if(win && win.isVisible()) {

win.show();

}

else {

if (win)

win.show();

}

})

notification.show();

lastNotification = notification

}`